# PHP script to remove all lines of the file except last n lines

Tags: php

How can I remove all the lines except the last n lines of the text file?

What code should I use to remove other lines except for last two lines ? 
I have one script which does opposite as this one :

```
$lines_array = file("./home/userdata/log.ini");
$new_output = "";
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
$new_output .= $lines_array[$i];
}
file_put_contents("./home/userdata/log.ini");
```

This code will delete all lines except first 5 lines.

Can you improve the above code and write the code that will delete all line except last 5 lines ?

Comment: why can't you use this code but change the conditions of the `for()` loop?

Comment: >>file_put_contents("./home/userdata/log.ini");<< oh this should belong to false .. file_put_contents expect min 2 params

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply get the number of lines, and use that to know the line numbers for the last two lines:

```
$lines_array = file("./home/userdata/log.ini");
$lines = count($lines_array); 
$new_output = "";
for ($i=$lines-2; $i<$lines; $i++){
$new_output .= $lines_array[$i];
}
file_put_contents("./home/userdata/log.ini", $new_output );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
$lines_array = file("./home/userdata/log.ini");
$new_output = array();
$new_output[] = array_pop($lines_array);
$new_output[] = array_pop($lines_array);
$new_output = array_reverse($new_output);
file_put_contents("./home/userdata/log.ini", implode("", $new_output));
```